# Rails where not is not finding nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I am trying to search to see if a posts value is either false or nil.

```
Post.where.not(:top_card => true)
```

This only returns the false values. I have confirmed that if I do either of the following it returns the correct values

```
Post.where(:top_card => false)
```

or

```
Post.where(:top_card => nil)
```

Any idea how I can get the posts with either the nil and false value?

Am I using the wrong method to search?

Comment: Try with `Post.where(top_card: [false, nil]`.

Comment: @Vucko That worked perfectly, how does the [] work? Does it treat it like an array that it just iterates over finding all the values for? Also if you submit that as an answer I will make it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like `Post.where(top_card: [false, nil]`.

Which will produce `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (posts.top_card IN (false, nil))`

See more at [Rails guides - Subset Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions).

Comment: I think the following should also work: `Post.where("top_card != ?", true)`

Comment: I am curios to know why code `Post.where.not(:top_card => true)` in the question does not work ?

Comment: It should work. Create a new question with you issue and post your code.

Comment: @Humza that does not work.

The accepted answer is fine for a boolean value where possibilities are very few, but does not help on a string field

e.g. `User.where.not(status: "active")` will not return users with status nil

Comment: @VijayMeena see [this post for an explanation](https://forum.upcase.com/t/why-does-where-not-on-string-columns-ignores-null-values/3167)

Answer (score 1):

`Post.where("top_card != ? OR top_card IS NULL")`

NOTE that this will work with string fields while the accepted answer by @Vucko will not. i.e. in cases where you cannot put an exhaustive list of all options in the query.

e.g. this will work

`User.where.not("status != ? OR status IS NULL", "active")`

thanks to [this forum](https://forum.upcase.com/t/why-does-where-not-on-string-columns-ignores-null-values/3167)